# SAS length of the value of the macro variable exceeds the maximum length

Tags: macros, sas

Hi I am trying to call a macro for each row in the data set using the code below

```
proc sql;
select cats('%run_procreg(name=',name,',month=',month,')') into :macrocalllist
  separated by ' ' from dataset_a;
quit;


&macrocalllist;
```

I am getting the 'variable maximum length' error:

> SAS length of the value of the macro variable MACROCALLLIST (65540)
>   exceeds the maximum length (65534). The value has been
>   truncated to 65534 characters.

because of the number of rows in the data set. Could you suggest a work-around?

Thank you,

Comment: How many rows are in your dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CALL EXECUTE is one option.  It allows you to generate a series of macro calls using data from a dataset, without storing the macro invocations in a macro variable.

For example:

```
%macro testprint(data=,obs=);
  proc print data=&data (obs=&obs);
  run;
%mend testprint;

data _null_;
  input datasetname $13. obs;
  call execute('%nrstr(%testprint(data='||datasetname
                               ||',obs='||put(obs,1.)
                               ||'))'
               );
  cards;
sashelp.shoes 3
sashelp.class 5
;
```

And the log will show:

```
NOTE: CALL EXECUTE generated line.
131  ;
1   + %testprint(data=sashelp.shoes,obs=3)    
NOTE: There were 3 observations read from the data set SASHELP.SHOES.   
2   + %testprint(data=sashelp.class,obs=5)    
NOTE: There were 5 observations read from the data set SASHELP.CLASS.
```